# Bug in a for-loop-copy vs std::copy which I don't understand

Tags: c++, for-loop, iterator, fifo

Below is a very simple (stripped from most of the template code) fifo buffer for a serial output interface. I decided to write my own because a) I'm trying to learn C++, b) the container adapter `queue` doesn't bring with it the "quickly-put-many" facility, enforcing an explicit `push()` for every element. I know that many modern compilers in many circumstances may optimize this, but for the sake of a) I wanted to do this myself - feel free to comment on the idea and any style/methodic errors you deem noteworthy.

The question however just deals with the inner loop of the "quickly-put-many" function `put()`. Compiled with the `std::copy()` variant, everything looks ok, but with my own version of the insertion (`-DBUGGY`), the data is partially clobbered.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <queue>
#include <chrono>



struct SerialBuffer
{
  std::array<char,127> fifo{};
  std::atomic<int8_t> hd = 0, tl = 0, vtl = 0;

  int8_t space(void) // return free space in queue
  {
    volatile int8_t tmp = hd - vtl - 1;
    if (tmp < 0) { tmp += 127; }
    return tmp;
  }

  int8_t reserve(int8_t n) // move virtual tail at once, reserving a run of bytes at end
  {
    volatile int8_t new_vtl = vtl;
    if (n <= space()) {
      if (new_vtl - 127 + n >= 0) { vtl = new_vtl - 127 + n; }
      else { vtl = new_vtl + n; }
      return new_vtl;
    }
    return -1;
  }

  int8_t next(int8_t i) // advance index in queue
  {
    if (i >= 127 - 1) { return 0; }
    return i + 1;
  }

  void confirm(void) // confirm the formerly reserved bytes as present in queue
  {
    tl = static_cast<int8_t>(vtl);
  }
  
  int8_t headroom(int8_t i) // return number bytes from queue index to queue end
  {
    return 127 - i;
  }
  
  template<typename iter_t>
  bool put(iter_t it, int8_t n) // (source, number of bytes)
  {
    int8_t i = reserve(n);

    if (i >= 0) {
      int8_t j = std::min(n, headroom(i)); // maybe two consecutive insert-ranges: first from i to buffer end, rest from buffer start

#ifdef BUGGY
      for (; i < 127; i++) {
        fifo[i] = *it++;
      }
      for (i = 0; i < n-j; i++) {
        fifo[i] = *it++;
      }
#else
      std::copy(it, it+j, fifo.begin()+i);
      std::copy(it+j, it+n, fifo.begin());
#endif
      
      confirm(); 
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
    
  bool put(std::vector<char> v) { return put(v.cbegin(),v.size()); }
  bool put(std::basic_string<char> v) { return put(v.cbegin(),v.size()); }

  
  void dump(int8_t k = 127)
  {
    if (space() < k) { hd = static_cast<int8_t>(tl); }
    else { hd = (hd + k) % 127; }
  }
  
  void print(void)
  {
    std::cout << "Head:" << (0+hd) << " Tail:" << (0+tl) << " VirtTail:" << (0+vtl) << std::endl;
    for (int8_t i = hd; i != tl; i = next(i)) { std::cout << fifo[i]; }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
};


int main(void)
{
  using namespace std::string_literals;
  
  SerialBuffer fifo1;
  auto tmp{"/uwb/x1/raw:123456789"s};
  std::vector<char> x(tmp.cbegin(),tmp.cend());

  std::queue<char,std::array<char,127>> fifo2;

  for (auto _: {1,2,3}) {
    for (int i=0; i < 10'000'000; i++) {
      if (!fifo1.put(x)) fifo1.dump();
    }
    fifo1.print();   
  }
}
```

Results:

```
$ g++ bug.cpp --std=c++17 -O3 && ./a.exe
Head:52 Tail:115 VirtTail:115
/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789
Head:104 Tail:103 VirtTail:103
/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789
Head:28 Tail:70 VirtTail:70
/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789

$ g++ bug.cpp --std=c++17 -O3 -DBUGGY && ./a.exe
Head:52 Tail:115 VirtTail:115
/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789
Head:104 Tail:103 VirtTail:103
▒ե▒qс▒▒1▒3▒▒wb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789
Head:28 Tail:70 VirtTail:70
/uwb/x1/raw:123456789/uwb/x1/raw:123456789
```

As you can see, there are garbled bytes in the second run. I am puzzled where my error in those seemingly harmless for loops is.

EDIT: As @yzt pointed out, this was an embarrasing simple logic error. I wrote a (correct) first `for` based version, then changed to `std::copy` then, too late in the evening, tried to measure the runtime difference by rewriting the `for` loops, this time wrong. Sorry all, this was a derivative of the "don't commit and go home when it doesn't run" error. Correct code:

```
  n -= j;
  for (; j > 0; j--,i++) {
    fifo[i] = *it++;
  }
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    fifo[i] = *it++;
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like a suitable case for using a debugger. BTW, a good practice is to avoid _magic numbers_ such as 127 in your code. If you defined a constant instead, then, you would be able to easily switch to a much smaller `fifo` array more suitable for debugging. See [What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/580083).

Comment: @DanielLangr as I said, I stripped all the template code and `constexpr` etc. to remove visual noise. The real code uses adaptive data types for the index and element types `SerialBuffer<typename elem_t, size_t buffer_size>` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One bug is that in your first loop, when you start from 0 (which happens even at first invocation,) you'd be incrementing the vector iterator 127 times, which clearly is out of range.

The copies work and your loops don't because your loops and the `std::copy` calls you are making are doing different things. They don't start or stop at the same indices, and therefore they aren't copying the same stuff.

Loops similar to the copies would be:

```
for (ptrdiff_t index = 0; index < j; ++index)
    *(fifo.begin() + i + index) = *(it + index); // the exact way you dereference isn't important; could have used array subscripting
for (ptrdiff_t index = 0; index < n - j; ++index)
    *(fifo.begin() + index) = *(it + j + index);
```

Also, I'd suggest you use a larger type than `int8_t` (e.g `int`) for your internal, intermediate calculations. There might be some overflows or miscalculations lurking in there.